# How to disable/hide menu bar tooltips/hints in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

How do I hide these pesky menu bar tooltips i.e. Borders / Fill color / Horizontal align, etc. They get in my way too often.

Here is an image...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QKy_-8MsDq_-LiEse_ORkhKNiD8xddTx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please _only_ use the official image host. Paste your image into the question while editing.

Answer (score 0):

cell tooltips can be hidden with the `×` and menubar with `^` button on the right

[image]

---

### update:

> [image]

you can do this too but not directly/within google sheets. you can do it for example with Adblock Plus option "Block element"

[image]

where you clock:

```
docs.google.com##.jfk-tooltip
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am more interested in hiding the menu bar tooltips.

Comment: @LinusVisser got a screenshot?

Comment: image inserted.

Comment: @LinusVisser answer updated