# Google Sheets Disable Cell Error Message Tooltip

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to disable error message tooltip being reflected in a cell, sharing below image for more clarification:

[image]

I checked question posted at below link having slight similar issue, however, this is not solving my query.

[How to disable/hide menu bar tooltips/hints in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73344237/how-to-disable-hide-menu-bar-tooltips-hints-in-google-sheet)

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

adblockplus to the rescue:

```
docs.google.com##.annotation-attribution.annotation-attribution-invalid
```

[image]

and reload your spreadsheet with **<kbd>F5</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks Player0 for the suggested solution, this is via a third party tool, is there any way to do this without any third party tool?

Comment: @Essem at this moment I am not aware of any alternative